# Convert C++ to Template Meta program

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to write simple c++ function (or really any other language) and then turn it into a Template Meta function (with some sort of converter tool).

For example the following:

```
int GetGreatest(int a, int b){
  if (a > b)
    return a;
  return b;
}
```

And converts it to:

```
template<int a,int b>
struct GetGreatest{
  static int value = a > b ? a : b;
};
```

Does any c++ function to template meta function converter exist or should I just brave the world of meta programming? (yes I know I could use `constexpr`, but I want to use templates)

Comment: I don't really understand what it is that you want. A program that automatically converts an arbitrary C++ function into something that runs as compile-time?

Comment: "STL Meta program" -- there's no such thing. For starters, there's no STL any more. Not for the longest time. We have something called a "C++ library".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry........ __Template__ Meta program

Comment: What do you mean by "does anything like this exist"? Clearly you've just written down "something like this".

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry....Does any arbitrary c++ function to template function converter exist (I will add this to my post)

Comment: There's actually a huge amount of converters that do just this. They're called programmers.

Answer (score 2):

We can't prove that there is no tool in the world to do this, but it would be exceptionally difficult to write such a tool for cases beyond those so simple that they are easily solved by "code snippets" in an IDE.

If we wanted to build such a tool, we could use Clang (or the old GCC-XML) to parse the runtime C++ function, and then try to "compile" it into a template metaprogram.  However, TMP is rather more art than science, and writing this compiler would be quite a bit of work because of all the tricks (some extremely nasty and non-obvious) which are employed by TMP authors.

Comment: @DarthRubik: Rats are remarkably resilient, versatile, and even intelligent creatures.  However, I have doubts as to whether even an army of rats would be able to reliably compile runtime functions into compile-time ones.  Now if you have a million monkeys, maybe....

Comment: I guess I just have to learn the agony of template meta programming (although hiring an army of trained programming monkeys does sound useful)

Comment: @DarthRubik: Alternatively, *don't* do any of that and just get on with your life. A vast number of useful programs have been written that don't need any or only tiny amounts of TMP. You don't need to do something that you don't enjoy.